# SCP (Sequential Convex Programming) vs SQP (Sequential Quadratic Programming)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Can someone explain me at a high level the difference between an SCP and an SQP to solve a nonlinear (nonconvex) program?

Assume my problem is something like

$$\min_x. \quad  f(x)$$
$$\text{s.t. }\quad g(x) \leq 0 $$

where both $f$ and $g$ are (in general) nonconvex.

My understanding is that (regardless or trust-region or line-search variants) SCP tackles the problem by forming a convex approximation of the objective $\tilde f$ around the current iterate $x^k$ and similarly linearise the constraints $g(x) \approx \tilde g(x) = g(x^k) + \nabla g(x^k)(x-x^k)$ and solve the the convex subproblem

$$\min_x. \quad  \tilde f(x)$$
$$\text{s.t. }\quad \tilde g(x) \leq 0 $$

to obtain the next iterate $x^{k+1}$ or at least the direction $d$ such that $x^{k+1} = x^k + \alpha d$.

In the same vein as far as my understanding goes SQP find the next iterate by solving the quadratic problem

$$\min_x. \quad  \hat f(x)$$
$$\text{s.t. } \quad \hat g(x) \leq 0 $$

where $\hat g = g(x^k) + \nabla g(x^k)(x-x^k)$ and $\hat f(x) = f(x^k) + \nabla f(x^k)d + d B_k d$ where $B_k$ is the Hessian or an approximation of it.

So is the difference between the two methods just the assumed shape of the convex approximation of the objective $f$ ?

Or am I missing some details?

Comment: One difference is how equality constraints are treated. SQP uses an active set method whereas SCP can use an active set but can also use an interior point method or other algorithm. Another difference is that SCP is targeted at nonconvex problems and has a trust region whereas SQP is primarily targeted at convex problems.

Comment: @ LinAlg Whoa Nelly. SQP can and is applied to non-convex problems, with suitable implementation of SQP, that is.